# Retrieve Spring Externalized String for Internationalization in Form .java file

Tags: java, spring, datetime, model-view-controller, internationalization

I was wondering what/if there is an equivalent to the following that is done on the presentation layer to retrieve externalized Spring messages in my message.properties files by locale. This is how it's done on the View:

```
<spring:message code="ejournal.starttransaction"/>
```

I ask this because there are some SimpleDateFormats that need internationalized that currently look like the following in my form .java file :

```
private SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
private SimpleDateFormat sdfDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
private SimpleDateFormat sdfTime=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
```

Those hardcoded date formats would be nice to retrieve from a messages.properties file much like how my View calls for internationalized text.

I'm sorry if this sounds like a very naive or uninformed question, but while looking around nothing seems to quite get to the same topic as this question. If anyone has suggestions in how to accomplish this just let me know or suggested reading for some beginners.

If you need any further code snippets, just let me know!

Edit -

A message source does exist. Attempting to work with this via annotations now per one answer.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
      <list>
        <value>/WEB-INF/messages/message</value>
      </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Edit 2 -

Spring version is 2.5.4.

Comment: Use `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance`, `DateFormat.getDateInstance` and `DateFormat.getTimeInstance` respectively, which return the format for the current `Locale` but also allow you to pass a `Locale`

Comment: Yeah, I do believe those would work in most instances and is probably best practice, but I believe our requirements differ from the "standard" locales provided by these. I will give these a try and see if they match our locale preferences, though, and maybe it will do some convincing for folks who think it ought to be another way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spring MVC, you can configure a ResourceBundleMessageSource as below

```
<bean name="messageSource" 
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" >
    <property name="basename" value="ScreenMessages" />
</bean>
```

You would then have a file for each locale. For instance

- US English (en_US) - ScreenMessage_en_US.properties
- Chinese - ScreenMessage_zh_CN.properties
- default - ScreenMessage.properties

ResourceBundleMessageSource is a locale sensitive bean and it will load the appropriate file based on locale.

In your Java class, you could then retrieve the date format using @Value annotation in your bean like below

```
@Value("#{ejournal.dateFormat}")
private String dateFormat;
```

@Value annotation is available only from spring 3. If you are using Spring 2.5, then inject ResourceBundleMessageSource into your bean

```
@Autowired
private ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;
```

Now you can retrieve the properties as below using locale

```
Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
String dateFormat = messageSource.getMessage('ejournal.dateFormat',null,locale);
```

Comment: Will try, thanks! I believe we already have a messageSource set up in the project since we have property files like message_fr_CA.properties and all, but it wasn't my doing and all so just trying to navigate the app and all.

Comment: Well, I added the following in our message.properties file which you can see the message source mapping in my question now in the edit.

ejournal.dateFormat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Then imported...

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

and tried the snippet you had on the dateFormat, and Eclipse suggested a change that ultimately did the import for me (likely a jar import with this, maybe we are working with an old Spring version?) and dateFormat doesn't seem to get set past null causing a null pointer down the line. Advice or need more info?

Comment: Finding out the Spring version now, if that helps at all... Have to import SpringVersion to check that, though.

Edit - Spring version is 2.5.4.

Comment: It appears Eclipse was asking to import the spring-beans 3.1.2 release jar. Not sure if those versions are independent of each-other, or if they would be compatible.

Comment: Ok that annotation is not available in Spring 2.5. I'll edit the message with an alternative solution.

Comment: I'll give this a try now, thanks for re-evaluating it!